# <li> not pushing down subsequent <li>

Tags: css, html-lists

I am creating a responsive mobile version of my website. As you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/306pfgs3/), when a user hovers `<li>` item, the menu opens up but overlays the `<li>` instead of expanding the menu.

I have added `display: block` in various places and `width: 100%` hoping that would fix the issue.

What do I need in the code for the menu to expand with a `<ul>` tag correctly once hovering over an `<li>` tag?

Comment: Demo please? We need to see full HTML/CSS for the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/306pfgs3/ Link in the post; fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pushing the menu down because it's positioned absolutely, therefore being removed from the normal document flow.

Remove all `position:absolute` statements from the `li ul` selector.

Working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/306pfgs3/1/

Comment: Maybe it's something else. http://beta.flyeurova.com/en/index.php Have a look here, if you resize the window to a tablet/mobile size, the issue is still there with your code. Username: `feu_admin` Password: `b3t4f3u`

Comment: Of course that might cause some other undesired effects, but the only way to have the expanding sub elements push the rest of the menu down is by not using absolute positioning.  What other issue are you experiencing now?

Comment: Updated my first post.

Comment: Did you remove position:absolute from both places?  It's also being defined for the mobile view (sub 768px wide).  Have a look inside @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}

Comment: Yes, both removed on `li ul` and `media`. However I did add it just now for `min-width: 768px`, as it messes up the horizontal menu on bigger resolutions.

Comment: I see multiple issues in your code.  The a.menu-item class should not be absolutely positioned either, and the containing li elements cannot have a fixed height of 33px.  Fix that and see where you stand then.

Comment: Where can you see it being positioned absolutely? I have removed the fixed heights, and the menu has collapsed completely.

Comment: This is still present in your CSS:

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
   ul#topnav li a {
    position: absolute;
   ... some other styles ...
}

Comment: Looks much better now :)

Comment: Yep, getting closer :)

Comment: Ok, I should be good from there! Thank you; maybe you also know why the content below the menu isn't being pushed?

Comment: Most likely because ul#topnav has a fixed height of 40 something pixels.  You need to remove that.   Have it change height according to it's contents by using height:auto; or not specifying any height at all.